# Dealing with dust mites

Tags: pest-control, dust

I know a lot of people have dust mite allergy, so drop your tips here if you have any handy hints.
Good vacuum cleaners ?
Things that poison them ?
Bedding covers ?
tnx

Answer (score 1):

- Vacuum frequently (little or no advantage to expensive models).
- Vacuum *everywhere* feasible, e.g., under mattress, books and behind furniture.
- Avoid forced air heating. Best is radiant, with no dust-gathering surface, and forced-hot water is also good.
- Check with an allergist for ways to avoid dust and on [desensitization](https://www.allergy-clinic.co.uk/allergies/more-about-allergy/desensitization-immunotherapy/) (immunotherapy).